# Compile times with boost::signals2 very slow

Tags: c++, performance, boost, visual-studio-2012, compilation

We have a large codebase which has successfully used boost::signals for years. We recently moved to boost v1.54 and decided that since boost::signals was deprecated we would switch to boost::signals2.

The issue we are seeing is that compile times are horrendous. For example, a small .cpp file will now take 20+ seconds where it used to take 4.

Similarly, one of our libraries (large) that used to take roughly 10 minutes to generate now takes up to an hour. I have searched all around for documentation on how to improve this through precompiled headers, macros, etc but have yet to find anything that improves the situation greatly.

Viewing cl.exe in procmon reveals a massive amount of IO into the boost::signals2 and mpl libraries.

We don't need the thread safety that signals2 provides at at this point we are close to pulling the plug on the 'upgrade' and reverting back to signals. Does anyone have any suggestions or experience with this before we give up?

We are using VS2012 with plenty of RAM/disk/etc.

Comment: Are you using precompiled headers?

Comment: Signals2 uses variadic templates, they are emulated in VS2012 at significant cost. Fixed in VS2013.  Between Boost adapting to that and VS2013 landing on your desktop, give it a handful of months.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the information, I hadn't considered that. Given that it's not feasible for us to wait for VS2013 is the best course of action to revert back to the signals library in your opinion? As it is now, the code is unusable due to slow compilation times.

Comment: You already know that answer, no point in asking me.  My advice is worth what you paid for it.

Comment: Can you provide some code illustrating how you are using the signals? Our project uses boost::signals2 and we're stuck on VS2005 and I have not encountered this problem. We are using precompiled headers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a project I worked on, all boost signals usages were pimpled such that forward declarations  are sufficient. This reduces compile time significantly as the signals2 definitions are only parsed when actually needed. Instead of providing a public `boost::signals2::signal` member, the class has a private std::unique_pointer member and provides a public connectToX function which returns a std::unique_pointer object.

```
class Subject {
public:
    boost::signals2::signal<void (int)> valueChanged;
    void setValue(int x) {
        valueChanged(x);
    }
};

class A {
public:
    A(Subject& subject): conn( subject.sig.connect( [&](int x) {this->onChange(x);} ) {}
    ~A() {conn.disconnect();}
private:
    void onChange(x) {}

    boost::signals2::connection conn;
};
```

then becomes a header with only forward declarations and no includes of boost signals2 headers:

```
// Header file
class Subject {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<boost::signals2::connection> connect(std::function<void (int)> observer);

private:
    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> mImpl;
};
```

Classes not interested in signals now do not need to parse signals2 headers. It is worth noting that in my experience most time is not spent parsing in the compiler, but in the linker. every compilation unit using boost signals contains a lot of instantiated functions which generate debug information and have to be eliminated by the linker at the end. And given that the MS linker is single-threaded and really slow, this is where the time is spent doing IO. A SSD provided a nice speed-up here.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. This is a very good idea (although it's unfortunate that such dancing is necessary).  We didn't consider using a pimpl in our case mainly because the use was so widespread that the change would be substantial. Another wrinkle is that clients of the signals would at times use the scoped_connection paradigm.
We are currently upgrading our project files to VS2013 so I will be interested to see if @Hans Passant's comments above are true.

Comment: Yes, the pimpl makes it quite more complex to use signals, especially because you have to return unique_ptrs with the connections. I am quite interested in the results for VS2013, although I don't work on a windows platform at the moment. I won't expect too much improvement because the linker has not been improved greatly, and this is where our build time was spent (together with writing pdb files with a lot of boost signals instantiations). You can use cl /Bt+ or link /time+ to get some build time measurements.